# Functionally create an array of positions (with Underscore/Lowdash)

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash

There is a grid of cells. The integer dimensions are stored in an array. How could this array of dimensions be reduced (or otherwise transformed) into an array containing an arrays of all possible cell positions?

For example, given a size of the grid is in an array (`[2,2]`) how could the list of positions (`[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]`) be produced without a for loop? (Possibly with lodash or underscore?)

*I am sure this is possible. I had go when before realising I was procrastinating and the following for loop would work:*

```
var size = [ 2, 3 ];
var positions = [];

for ( var x = 0;  x < size[0]; ++x ) {
    for ( var y = 0;  y < size[1]; ++y ) {
        positions.push( [ x, y ] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_.range` with underscore.js like this :

```
_.range(size[0] * size[1]).map(function(i) { 
    return [ Math.floor(i / size[1]), i % size[1] ]; 
});
```

---

**EDIT :** I have added some jsfiddle you can play with : http://jsfiddle.net/23Lsu6vp/

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**times**](http://underscorejs.org/#times) a couple of times and then shallow [**flatten**](http://underscorejs.org/#flatten) the resulting arrays:

```
    var data = _.times(size[0], function(x){
        return _.times(size[1], function(y){
            return [x,y];
        });
    });

    var positions = _.flatten(data, true);
```

Comment: +1, you should make it a (recursive) function that takes `[2,2]` as input